# Magento 2 - set up cronjob

Tags: magento2

I've searched for 2 hours how to set up a cronjob in Magento 2, without success.

I've tried it like the [Magento Support Page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron%22) suggested. I've logged into the SSH server of my provider with Putty.exe and tried to start the command:

```
crontab -u <Magento file system owner user name> -e
```

Of course with the Magento File owner name, but crontab can't be found as a command.

sudo or su for installing crontab doesn't work either. How do I install the cronjob then?

My PHP version is 7.0.1.

Comment: Each user can usually have their own crontab so you shouldn't need sudo. You should be able to just `crontab -e` with out sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like crontab isn't installed. If you're using Debian/Ubuntu you can try to install it with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cron
```

Comment: I am using Putty for a SSH access. sudo doesn't work either

Comment: Are you logged in as root? if yes. Just do the commands without sudo in the front.